# Не могу понять как решить задачу по java

Tags: java

```
package java3;

public class Main {

    static final int MAX_INDEX = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here          
        int lo = 1;
        int hi = 1;
        String mark;
        System.out.println("1:" + lo);
        for (int i = 2; i < MAX_INDEX; i++) {
            if ((hi % 2) == 0) {
                mark = " *";
            } else {
                mark = "";
            }
            System.out.println(i + ": " + hi + mark);
            hi = lo + hi;
            lo = hi - lo;
        }
    }
}
```

По заданию:

Измените вычисление чисел Фибоначчи так, чтобы создаваемые в нем объекты String сначала сохранялись в массиве, и выводились на экран в конце программы.

Вопрос о каком понятии String идет речь? Если у меня только int. И как сохранять в массиве значения?

Comment: Я думаю вам надо спросить того кто дал вам это задание.

Comment: Как я понял, вам нужно приводить тип ```Integer``` к ```String``` для вывода, т.к. Java пошлет вас куда по дальше если вы захотите вывести только числа. Для начала определитесь какой массив вам нужен, если чисел конечное число - можно использовать определенный массив с конечным числом элементов, в ином случае можно использовать ```List```.

Answer (score 1):

Задача состоит в том чтобы исключить все `println` из алгоритма(который желательно вынести в отдельную функцию), просто собирая данные, необходимые для вывода.
Вывод осуществить по собранным данным.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    static final int MAX_INDEX = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        // TODO code application logic here          
        int lo = 1;
        int hi = 1;
        String mark;
        //System.out.println("1:" + lo);
        results.add("1:" + lo);

        for (int i = 2; i < MAX_INDEX; i++) {
            if ((hi % 2) == 0) {
                mark = " *";
            } else {
                mark = "";
            }
            // System.out.println(i + ": " + hi + mark);
            results.add(i + ": " + hi + mark);
            hi = lo + hi;
            lo = hi - lo;
        }

        for (String row : results) {
          System.out.println(row);
        }

    }
}
```